# Find the lowest common divisor greater than N?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a given set of numbers, I need to find the lowest common divisor that's higher than a given number, N. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean the least common *multiple* that is greater than $N$?

Comment: No. I do mean a _divisor_.

Comment: @shesek Any common divisor divides the gcd and every divisor of gcd is a common divisor. Hence, what you are after is $$\min \{d| \gcd(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k): d > N\}$$ Is this what you are after and am I interpreting your question correctly?

Comment: I’d find the gcd $d$ of the set of numbers. If I could easily find its prime factorization, I’d do so, and from that I’d find the smallest subproduct bigger than $N$.

Comment: @Marvis I think you are, tho I'm not quite sure what that formula means (not much of a math background, I'm a programmer). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So I would generate all the possible subproducts of the prime factors, than find the lowest one bigger than N? Or is there a better way to do that? I'm trying to implement as an software algorithm, in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: If I were programming it, I don’t think that I’d bother with the prime factors: factorization tends to be difficult. You might find that a simple search from $N+1$ to $d$, testing each number to see whether it divides $d$ and picking the first hit, is the way to go.

Comment: Actually, I think I found another way to accomplish what I'm trying to implement in my software. I asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/218210/45513. Thanks for all the help!